# helper function that uses Http module

Tags: angular

I want to make a simple helper function that uses the Http module to send out requests.

```
export function serverLog(input) {
    http.post('server-log', input);
}
```

But I don't know how to inject the Http as dependency.

Answer (score 5):

I would create an HTTP interceptor that extends `Http`:

```
import { Http, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer';

export class HttpService extends Http {


    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.request(url, options));
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.get(url, options));
    }

    post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.post(url, body, options));
    }

    put(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.put(url, body, options));
    }

    delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.intercept(super.delete(url, options));
    }


    intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable

            .finally(() => {
                serverLog(...) <-- log here
            });
    }
}
```

Import it into your module like this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, LoadingComponent],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: Http,
            useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
                return new HttpService(backend, options);
            },
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I don't want the serverLog() to fire for all requests, I want a function like console.log(), that I can use where ever I want in my code to send data to the server